# Google App Engine Standard Python Cloud Build

Tags: docker, dockerfile, google-cloud-build

Background:
Trying to automate my build process using the new Google Cloud Build 
1. I am using Angular 6.x
2. I am using python google app engine standard

I followed the instructions here: 
https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/build-test-deploy-artifacts#deploying_artifacts

Cloud Build is deploying my application after a trigger based on a changes to a cloud repository.

However my app uses 3rd party python libraries which are installed in the lib folder described here:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27

When cloud build runs I want it to also install the python libraries from requirements

This is my cloudbuild.yaml file

```
steps:
# Use npm
#- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
#  args: ['install', '-t', 'static/app', '.']
##- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
##  args: ['test', '-t', 'static/app', '.']
#- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
#  args: ['build', '-t','static/app', '.']

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/my-project', '.']

- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  args: ["app", "deploy"]

timeout: "1600s
```

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:2.7

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN pip install -t lib -r requirements.txt

##This does not help/work##
COPY /app/lib .
```

It is pulling down the libraries with pip but struggling trying to find the right syntax to copy the modules back to the host? Any Docker experts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I removed the docker file, it is not needed.

Added a build step to my cloudbuild.yaml file

```
- name: "docker.io/library/python:2.7"
  args: ['pip', 'install', '-t', '/workspace/lib', '-r', '/workspace/requirements.txt']
```

This installs the python 3rd party libraries for my app engine app.